# Как сделать запрещенные сайты в боте

Tags: javascript, node.js

У меня бот на nodejs для бессед вк. Но бота легко можно слить если использовать команду !news.
Данная команда пишет текст который написал модератор + добавляет картинку тревоги.
Некие умные люди берут и банят бота, сначала вводят !news и через пробел пишут сайт вкмикс например, а сами жалуются на спам и бота банят.
Как можно запретить все эти сайты и слова типо "по*но" и т.п?

Comment: А чем Вам `по*но` не угодило?

Comment: Вконтакте за это блочит!

Comment: Наверное, регулярные выражения надо использовать. Но это только мое предположение

Comment: @Dady, Вот лицемеры!

Comment: @Дмытрык, мне кажется, что регуляркой тут не обойтись, потому что сегодня пишут `по*но`, завтра `по*н0`, нужно много китайских детей, которые будут писать каждый день новую регулярку.

Comment: @Дмытрык, [ни в коем случае](http://lurkmore.to/%D0%92%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B4%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D1%80#.D0.9B.D1.83.D0.BB.D0.B7.D1.8B).